# How do I get webpack to compile the main.js file in app/js directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create a Reactjs app. I have created the folder then executed:

```
npm install webpack -g
```

Then I executed:

```
npm init
```

Completed the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "reactquiz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a Reactjs quiz app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Daniel Cortes",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.13.*",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.*",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1"
  }
}
```

Then I executed webpack locally:

```
npm install webpack --save-dev
```

Then I created the `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module.export = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'app/js/main.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    }

}
```

And I realized I still do not have a `main.js` file in `app/js`. I have looked at the webpack documentation, I have looked here, I have looked at tutorials. What is the proper way to install webpack so it generates the file in `app/js/main.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename doesn't look right, the correct format is:

```
filename: './app/js/main.js'
```

Additionally, you didn't "execute webpack", you installed it. Did you execute the command `webpack` after that too?

Comment: so after npm install webpack --save-dev, I would execute webpack and this will install the main.js file?

Comment: Executing `webpack` transpiles your source into the `main.js` file, yes. There are many other things webpack can do, `webpack` is just the default command.

Comment: I was looking at the webpack website and the setup is totally different than what I am doing here. It seems maybe what I am doing is outdated? I executed "webpack" and that did not transpile my source into the main.js file.

Comment: Then I don't know where you're looking.. http://webpack.github.io/docs/usage.html#moving-to-a-configuration-file What happened instead?

Comment: I wasn't looking at the documentation to build this app. I was building it the same way I built a previous app. Looks like things have totally changed. In the past I just installed webpack globally, did the npm init, developed the json file, then did an npm install and moved on with creating my files and that's it. Initially, I thought installing webpack globally was enough to continue to create more apps, but then I learned that you had to install it locally "npm install webpack --save-dev", but it seems like there is much more

Comment: You don't have to install it locally, but without triggering the build process, why should anything happen? Anyway, without more information or error messages, we can't help you.

Comment: Hey Sven, I am not getting an error message so much as the site when I go to localhost:8080/app is not rendering and when I go into source I see the html with the script referring to "js/main.js" but when I click on it, obviously there is nothing there because that file does not exist. So I have provided the steps I have taken thus far which I expected would have created that file. So in the past I have done npm install webpack -g, then npm init, added dependencies to the json file, npm install...done and apparently that does not work anymore.

Comment: And what happens when you type `webpack` into the console?

Comment: This is what I get when I type webpack into the console: ldco2016@DCortes-MacBook-Pro-3 ~/Projects/reactquiz $ webpack                                                                                                                                  [ruby-2.3.0]
webpack 1.13.2
Usage: https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html.